# How to not echo array if previous one's key has been echoed already

Tags: php, arrays

This is what I get after a `print_r($myArray)` (wrapped in pre) on my array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 203.143.197.254
    [1] => not/available
)
Array
(
    [0] => 40.190.125.166
    [1] => articles/not/a/page
)
Array
(
    [0] => 25.174.7.82
    [1] => articles/not/a/page
)
```

How would I return or echo just the first two in this case (no regex), given the fact that I would like to only output each array whose [1] value has not been echoed before?

My list as far more entries and $myArray[1] is sometimes the same, I want to skip echoing the same thing.

I have tried array_unique but I can't get it to work as param 1 is expected to be an array.

```
print_r(array_unique($myArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.  Didn't do a full copy paste job but hopefully you get the idea of the logic

```
$echoed = array();
foreach($array as $arr) {
    if(!in_array($arr[1],$echoed)) {
        echo $arr[1];
        $echoed[] = $arr[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand the approach, it doesn't work though, there's something wrong with the if as I get a `Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1`

Comment: Could be something how you are using it.  Copying and pasting the above code runs without warnings/errors for me (when array is not empty)

Answer (score 0):

```
$echoedBefore = array();
print_r(array_filter($myArray, function($entry) {
    global $echoedBefore;
    $alreadyEchoed = in_array($entry[1], $echoedBefore);
    if (!$alreadyEchoed) {
        $echoedBefore[] = $entry[1];
    }
    return !$alreadyEchoed;
}));
```

Comment: I get `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in..`